# talend tRESTClient suspected issues with 204 No Content response without "content-length: 0" header

Tags: rest, http, talend

We use talend to build ETLs. One of the components we use is [tRESTClient](https://help.talend.com/reader/7NvFnkWpbH8Gy3Rm6mUXnw/V4DayMUD1TrO522ClO0fBw), to interact to a REST service in our platform. We use talend version 7.1.

Recently this REST service has changed the version of its HTTP server library ([libmicrohttpd](https://www.gnu.org/software/libmicrohttpd), the REST service is based in C/C++). In particular, has moved from limicrohttpd 0.9.48 to 0.9.70. And since we did the change, the integration in the ETL has started to fail. We see message likes this in the talend traces:

```
--------------------------------------
time=2020-08-05 08:26:01| lvl=INFO | ver=1.0| Inbound Message
----------------------------
ID: 1
Response-Code: 204
Encoding: ISO-8859-1
Content-Type: 
Headers: {Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], connection=[keep-alive], Date=[Wed, 05 Aug 2020 06:26:03 GMT], Expires=[0], fiware-correlator=[894f7ff0-d6e4-11ea-b1bd-fa163ec74401], Pragma=[no-cache], Referrer-Policy=[same-origin], Server=[nginx], Strict-Transport-Security=[max-age=31536000; includeSubdomains;], X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-Frame-Options=[SAMEORIGIN], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block]}
--------------------------------------
Exception in component tRESTClient_1 (VLCI_ETL_MEDIOAMBIENTE_INSERT_CB)
javax.ws.rs.client.ResponseProcessingException: Problem with reading the data, class org.dom4j.Document, ContentType: */*.
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.reportMessageHandlerProblem(ResponseImpl.java:437)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.doReadEntity(ResponseImpl.java:379)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.readEntity(ResponseImpl.java:314)
                at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.impl.ResponseImpl.readEntity(ResponseImpl.java:304)
              …
```

We are still investigating the problem but we suspect that one of the changes introduced in libmicrohttpd could be related. In particular, with libmicrohttd 0.9.48 (when the ETL works) “Content-Length: 0” header was included in 204 responses. With libmicrohttpd 0.9.70 (when ETL doesn’t work) such “Content-Length: 0” header is not included.

Is this a known issue? I mean, is tRESTClient (version 7.1) expected to fail if “Content-Lengh: 0” is not included in 204 responses?

Note that the HTTP specification is pretty clear regarding Content-Length usage in 204 responses. From RFC 7321 (which as far as I know is the normative standard on HTTP) [section 6.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.1):

> A server MUST NOT send a Content-Length header field in any response with a status code of 1xx (Informational) or 204 (No Content)”

so if tRESTClient is not supporting it, then I understand is a bug in talend (maybe solved in post-7.1 releases?)

Any feedback on this is really welcomed! Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Note that a similar issue has been posted in talend JIRA (https://jira.talendforge.org/browse/TESB-29906). However, we have realized that JIRA is not open, so probably StackOverflow is better place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, it seems we have solved the issue in the following way.

In the failing situation the component was using this configuration:

[image]

We have changed Accept Type from "JSON" to "Any" in the following way:

[image]

And now it is working.

My guess is that with Accept Type "JSON" the component is waiting for a response payload and this is problematic in the case of 204 No Content. Using "Any" removes that restriction.

Maybe it worked by chance with the non-standard `content-length: 0` header in this case... It's a bit weird anyway, I think the tRESTClient should deal with this situation better than this. Maybe is a behavior already fixed in the post-7.1 versions.

Any feedback or comment on this solution would be welcomed. Thanks!